# CSS: Why this left transformation doesn't work?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I am trying to make a **text** into a **circle** to move to te left. At the moment the text is on the age of the circle and I just want to make it go in when I hover over it...

```
.circle-yellow p
{
 position: absolute;
 top: 42px;
 left: 87px;
  -webkit-transition: left 500ms;
  -moz-transition: left 500ms;
  -ms-transition: left 500ms;
  -o-transition: left 500ms;
  transition: left 500ms;
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: white;
  font-family: "impact";
}

.circle-yellow:hover p 
{
   left:60px;
}
```

This the HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="circle-box">
    <div class="circle-yellow" id="js"><p>ARTWORK</p></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the CSS for wrapper, circle-box and circle-yellow

```
.wrapper 
{
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 width: 500px;
 height: 500px;
 margin-top: -250px; /* Half the height */
 margin-left: -250px; /* Half the width */
}
  .circle-box
  {
   height:100px;
   width:270px;
   display: block;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 90px;
  }

 .circle-yellow
 {
   position: relative;
   border-radius: 50%;
   width: 120px;
   height: 120px;
   border-style: solid;
    border-color: #ffbf1e;
   float:left;
 }
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lKLzg

Comment: I'm confused on what the exact problem is. Do you want the text to be completely outside the circle to begin with?

Comment: It seems to work fine. You have the p tag styled white so you can't see anything unless you set a background or add a non-white color to the hover style

Comment: What exactly is not working? I [looks good](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/cFIJd) to me

Comment: I am trying to make the P tag to move to left but IT IS NOT MOVING at all ..

Comment: it is working. tested it. what browser are you testing it?

Comment: What are you using? It works for me in Firefox and Chrome

Comment: Is the codepen in Dimitri's comment working in your browser?

Comment: I am using firefox, and usually this transofrmation works fine without me using this "circle classes" and the other stuff but when I want to use it inside the all of this wrappers and stuff then it doesn't work :(

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any other css or stuff that might be messing with it? It clearly works for all of us here.

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lKLzg this works for me

Comment: yeah it is working. The problem was because I have a circle splash and it was covering the other ones and when I gave z-index:1; and everything started to work ... : )